# Why doesn't this order of code work properly?

Tags: c++, logic, if-statement

So I've been working on part of this program for a few hours straight. I have a few lines of code that have stumped me for over an hour now. It just doesn't make sense. I read the lines over and over again and think in my head what it should do, but it's not doing it! It's probably some stupid mistake that I keep overlooking (usually happens to me..) or it could be from lack of sleep/constantly working on it for the last few hours.

The program is quite long, but the chunk of code I'm having issues with is only a few lines - so I'll only post the whole thing if needed.

---

Ok, so here is a quick run down of what this should be doing:

I have a single vector, filled with with manually set strings (19, each being 79 characters long). This 1 dimensional vector will be treated as a 2d vector - as i'm trying to keep it basic. So this vector of strings, if displayed 1 string per line, essentially creates a grid with rectangle sections of '.' and paths of '#' connecting the rectangle sections. It should get an x and y coordinate, passed to the function. It loops through like a 2d vector and finds the location. It checks to see if the char at the location is NOT '.' or '#' else, it changes the char to an X to mark its position. I set the testing up with a valid x,y coordinate that is the location of a '.' - The problem is right after the line where i cout "match found::: " When the program runs, it displays the value of vLevel[i][j] = '.' But for some reason, it doesn't go to the else statement where the function is called 4 more times and I put the cout statement. Heres what the grid looks like. The white spaces are spaces.. each line is a string in the vector:

```
.......                                                                    
.......  .......                                                           
.......##.......      ..........................                           
.......  .......      ..........................                           
         .......      ..........................     ..........            
         .......      ..........................#####..........            
                      ..........................     ..........            
                      ..........................           #               
                      ..........................           #               
                       #                                   #               
                       #                                   #               
    ........           #   ............                .......             
    ........           #   ............                .......             
    ........           #   ............    ....        .......             
    ........###############............    ....        .......             
    ........               ............####....                            
    ........               ............    ....
```

---

Heres the section of code I'm dealing with:

```
void markPosition(vector<string> & vLevel, int x, int y){
    cout << "x: " << x <<endl;
    cout << "y: " << y <<endl;

    bool doubleCheck = true; //extra bool I added for testing purposes

    for( int i = 0; i < vLevel.size(); i++ ){
            for( int j = 0; j < vLevel[i].size(); j++ ){
                    //displays if x and/or y are out of range
                    if (doubleCheck){
                            if ((x < 0) || (x > vLevel[i].size())){
                                    cout << "X is out of range!" << endl;
                                    doubleCheck = false;
                            }
                            if ((y < 0) || (y > vLevel.size())){
                                    cout << "Y is out of range!" << endl;
                                    doubleCheck = false;
                            }
                    }
                    else {
                            return;
                    }

                    if ((j == x) && (i == y)){
     //////THIS IS THE PROBLEM LOL
                            cout << "match found::: " << vLevel[i][j] << endl;
                            if ((vLevel[i][j] != '.') || (vLevel[i][j] != '#')){
                                    cout << "Located in the blankness" << endl;
                                    return;
                            }

                            else {
                                    cout << "I don't get reached!!??" << endl;
                                    vLevel[i][j] = 'X';
                                    markPosition(vLevel,i-1,j);
                                    markPosition(vLevel,i+1,j);
                                    markPosition(vLevel,i,j+1);
                                    markPosition(vLevel,i,j-1);
                           }
                      }
                }
        }
}
```

---

The spacing got messed up when pasting it, so i tried to clean it up a bit. I don't get why it skips the else. Like I said, I'm sure I'll feel dumb once this is resolved. I need sleep lol.

Let me know if you need more info. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at:

```
if ((vLevel[i][j] != '.') || (vLevel[i][j] != '#'))
```

This will *always* evaluate to `true`. Think about it.

(I think you meant `if((!=)&&(!=))` or `if(!((==)||(==)))`.)

Comment: Another programmer who's forgotten deMorgan's Law. :)

Comment: Dammit too slow.  Read it on my phone but had to login to the computer to properly cut and paste.  +1 for you speedy sir.

Comment: @ModdedLife Let's just suppose that `vLevel[i][j]` is equal to `'.'`.  What is the truth of the two parts of that logic expression, and what does the entire thing evaluate to?

Comment: DeMorgan's law doesn't make sense lol. Truth table-wise it does, but logically it plays tricks =/ I spent too long on that!

Comment: @c.fogelklou: Yeah, some questions fall to the narrow experts, some to the real geniuses, and some to whoever sees them first.